# Multiple tangent function

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a nonlinear function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, such that any tangent line is tangent to the graph of $f$ at two distinct points (at least)?

Comment: My intuition says no. I think you have a problem at the point where the derivative reaches its maximum, but I cannot yet prove it.

Comment: It could be a line where the derivative is minimal/ maximal.

Comment: @Ragnar the question asks for a *nonlinear* function.

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick, I meant a line, but only locally.

Answer (score 3):

I will prove there is no  $y=y(x)$ that solves $f'(x)=f'(y)$ while also solving $f(y)-f(x)=(y-x)f'(x) $ for all $x$, unless $y=x$ or $f$ is linear, with the assumptions that $y\in C^1$ and $f\in C^2$.  Assume it is true and take the derivative of the second equation to get

$y'(x)f'(y)-f'(x)=y'(x)f'(x)-f'(x)+(y-x)f''(x)$.

Letting $f'(x)=f'(y)$ hold, this expression simplifies to read

$0=(y-x)f''(x)$.

Therefore, either $y=x$, or $f''(x)=0$, and $f$ is a linear function.